# how to stub the :errors collection to act invalid when rspec tests a controller that uses respond_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails

I refactored my `OrgController` to use `respond_with` and now the controller spec scaffold is failing with this message:

```
1) OrgsController POST create with invalid params re-renders the 'new' template
   Failure/Error: response.should render_template("new")
     expecting <"new"> but rendering with <"">
```

The spec looks like this:

```
it "re-renders the 'new' template" do
 Org.any_instance.stub(:save).and_return(false)
 post :create, {:org => {}}, valid_session
 response.should render_template("new")
end
```

I've read that I should stub the `:errors` hash to make it look like there is an error.  What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Here is a gist of a proposed solution https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/pull/560/files but it doesn't work for me.  I get `undefined method full_messages for {:some=>["errors"]}:Hash`

Answer (score 15):

Using RSpec's new syntax which was introduced in v3, the stubbing would look like

```
allow_any_instance_of(Org).to receive(:save).and_return(false)
allow_any_instance_of(Org).to receive_message_chain(:errors, :full_messages)
  .and_return(["Error 1", "Error 2"])
```

The related controller code would look something like

```
if org.save
  head :ok
else
  render json: {
    message: "Validation failed",
    errors: org.errors.full_messages
  }, status: :unprocessable_entity # 422
end
```

Answer (score 5):

The message:

```
expecting <"new"> but rendering with <"">
```

suggests that it's a redirect not a render. Either your stubbing wasn't successful or your controller is but in the controller. 
You should be able to test if stubbing works with something like: `Org.first.valid?` or `Org.new(valid_attibutes).valid?`. For example stubbing will be broken if have `mocha` in your `Gemfile`, as in that case `any_instance` will be a `mocha` object, and rspec `stub` will not work on it.
If stubbing works you can debug what happens in the controller with either logging or debugger.

For stubbing errors you can do something like this:

```
Org.any_instance.stub(:errors).and_return(ActiveModel::Errors.new(Org.new).tap {
  |e| e.add(:name,"cannot be nil")})
```

Or if controller uses only `errors.full_messages` then you can:

```
Org.any_instance.stub_chain("errors.full_messages").and_return(["error1","error2"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should stub the valid? method:

```
Org.any_instance.stubs(:valid?).and_return(false)
```

then your object won't be saved since it will be invalid

Comment: It would appear that this works on the POST update with invalid params: `ActiveModel::Errors.any_instance.stub(:empty?).and_return(false)` but it doens't work on the PUT update with invalid params

Comment: Actually, it does work for both the POST and PUT operations but it seems like the wrong way to go about this.

Comment: ryan bates uses "stubs(:valid?)" instead of "stub(:valid?)", i guess that's the problem http://railscasts.com/episodes/71-testing-controllers-with-rspec?autoplay=true

Comment: I appreciate all your help, but I don't think this technique works. The stubs (with an *s*) method is part of the Mocha mocking framework.  Ryan preferred Mocha (circa 2007) because it supported the any_instance method before Rspec. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406692/what-are-the-advantages-of-mocha-over-rspecs-built-in-mocking-framework

Comment: Turns out that using respond_with when you want

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I was using a strict `save!` (that raises an error when validation fails).
 For that case, I used:

```
  allow_any_instance_of(ReportFile).to receive(:save!).and_raise(
    ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, ReportFile.new.tap do |rf|
      rf.errors.add(:data_file_size, 'must be less than 100 Megabytes')
    end
  )
```